# Streaming video from Beaglebone over Xbee module

Tags: xbee, video, beaglebone-black

I would like to stream a video feed from a camera connected to a Beaglebone Black wirelessly. However, we are talkig distances of over 4Km so I don't think a regular 2.4GHz connection would cut it. I have seen that there are Xbee modules available with an operating frequency of around 900MHz, which would be much more suited for the considered distances.
I have seen people connecting the Xbee to microcontrollers using UART, so I would like to know if using that method the Beaglebone would be able to recognize the Xbee as a "network adapter" and stream video to it, or if I have to use other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this due to distance and of course the UART protocol(single-ended) is not made for video streaming.You will need a LVDS(Low Voltage Differential Signal) for this.The distance of 4 Km is to big for a single wireless transmitter.You will need to use an available network which could be your relay.What resolution does the camera have ?

Comment: The current camera is 720p, but that is way over what we need, 360p would be more than enough. So you are saying we may need to use a "standard" network system= Maybe a router on the base station and a wireless adapter on the BB? But how could we achieve the desired distances then?

Comment: Do you have access to internet ?The distance is too big ,at this distance is quite impossible and might be illegal to transmit in that frequency band, is reserved.That's why the wifi is so weak, to not affect other people with you transmission.

Comment: We could integrate a GSM module, but I believe that would increase the latency to a point the video would be of no use

Comment: This is a remote device ?Give me more details about what you want to do

Comment: I need to implement a telemetry system for a race car. Among other sensor data, I need to stream a video feed from inside the car.

Comment: I understood, is a free space ? I mean not buildings.One solution is to use something that is already build, like : http://www.vfmstore.com/tr24.html which use NTSC or PAL.First time i thought that you want to transmit something Full HD.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29620/discussion-between-amiguels-and-stefan-merfu).